How to make pgn-extract duplicate detection consider headers?
I have a large-ish pgn composed from multiple sources - logically it has a lot of duplicate games.
I tried to filter it using pgn-extract duplicate detection:
pgn-extract --duplicates dupes.pgn --output unique.pgn file.pgn

My problem is, that duplicate detection only compares movetext and no headers - I would like to keep games that have different players, even if they had same moves played.
For example, using command as written these two games are considered same:
[White "Some white player"]
[Black "Some black player"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]
 
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5  1/2-1/2

[White "Some different white player"]
[Black "Some different black player"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]
 
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5  1/2-1/2

While I would like to consider them different. So which options do I need to use with pgn-extract to compare both movetext and headers when detecting duplicates?

I am afraid that that is not possible with pgn-extract. One issue that would need to be addressed is how to specify the tag-matching criteria, given that games often have different sets of tags, and - depending on the sources of the games - variations in the text of tags.

Understandable, thank you.
